# Issue while integrating GIT with STAT tool

Tags: git

I am facing below error while doing test connection from STAT tool to GIT hub. Please reply, your feedback would be appreciated.

```
$ git ls-remote "ssh://github.com/arjuncfc/stat"
```

> ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer fatal:
>   Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Thanks
Amit